# Utilizar o arquivo .htaccess com RewriteBase

Tags: apache, url-rewrite

Utilizo o arquivo .htaccess para escrita de URL's amigáveis, mas sempre tenho problema com os links das folhas de estilo e de imagens quando é feita uma reescrita que adiciona um nível ou retira.

Tipo: https://meusite.com/exemplo/ aponta para exemplo.html
e     https://meusite.com/exemplo/1 aponta para exemplo.html?exemplo=$1

A folha de estilo utilizada é a mesma, mas no segundo caso ela não carrega pois a url está diferente. Como posso corrigir isso usando o arquivo .htaccess?